# Row level trigger returning NULL causes ERROR: query has no destination for result data

Tags: triggers, data-partitioning

I have created a before insert trigger that should insert the data into either an existing table partition or create a new partition and then insert the data.
I see that the partition is created but then the error "ERROR:  query has no destination for result data" causes a rollback of the transaction and the partition along with the data is removed again.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION trg_insert_historytrails()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- First check if the event we are trying to insert exists in some partition, code omitted
    -- if the table exists (code omitted, working fine), enter the data 
    EXECUTE 'insert into historytrails' ||
        to_char(NEW.created, '_YYYY_"m"MM') ||
        ' values ( $1.* )' USING NEW;
    -- Prevent insertion into master table
    RETURN NULL;
EXCEPTION
WHEN undefined_table THEN

    -- this works just fine but at the end, the error causes a full rollback
    SELECT create_partition('historytrails', NEW.created);
    
    EXECUTE 'insert into historytrails' ||
        to_char(NEW.created, '_YYYY_"m"MM') ||
        ' values ( $1.* )' USING NEW;

    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS historytrail_insert ON historytrails;
CREATE TRIGGER historytrail_insert BEFORE INSERT
    ON historytrails FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_insert_historytrails();
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally found it. The issue was that the statement

```
SELECT create_partition('historytrails', NEW.created);
```

should have been:

```
PERFORM create_partition('historytrails', NEW.created);
```